# Is it possible to install Microsoft SqlDbLocal instance on Ubuntu 14 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, monodevelop, mssql

I have a complete code written in Visual Studio which I have ported to monodevelop in Ubuntu 14 LTS. I was thinking if there is a way to install the [Sql localDB instance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299) in Ubuntu 14.

Comment: I would be surprised if ther is such possibilty. That would mean that Windows has released a .deb file for their product, something unheard of!

Comment: It might be possible using Wine but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to do that. Even with Wine I don't think it will work. However, you can run your application on Ubuntu and install DB Server on another Windows computer. That should work. You could even install DB in virtual machine within your Ubuntu. Here you can find some more information on the topic: http://www.howtogeek.com/133515/4-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-linux/